# How to access to a Spring Data Rest response _links with Bowman library?

Tags: spring-data-rest, hal-json

On my client side i'm using Bowman library to consume a Spring Data Rest api. I'm trying to access to the "prev", "next", "last" of my _links node in my hal+json response.

How can i do that ?

I can access to the _links node of an object of my client model with the @LinkedResource annotation but how with _links node that contains the "prev", "first", "next" etc...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no support for pagination in Bowman library. It's a known issue ([See Github issue](https://github.com/BlackPepperSoftware/bowman/issues/23)) that has not been solved yet.